# PHP echo variable in div

Tags: php, echo

Help me please :) I have this code...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
$pid=$row ['pid'];
 echo '<div class="single"><div class="wrap">

 <div style="text-align:center;">
     <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/snarfer.php?id=<?php echo $pid ?>">Comments</a>

 </br>
<a href="MyOnlineStore/product.php?id=<?php echo $pid?>">View Details</a>
 </div>
 <a href="'.$path.$row['filename'].'" rel="lightbox[plants]" title="'.$row['alttext'].'"><img src="'.$path.$row['filename'].'" alt="Plants: image 1 0f 4 thumb" /></a>
 </div>
</div>';
}
```

i just wana know how to echo this $pid ?? tnx :)

Comment: Well, just like you did it in the code you provided. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @H2CO3 .. multiple things.  See the answers below.

Comment: @Daedalus yes of course... but OP's question is still hardly a question...

Answer (score 8):

Its considered a better practice to echo PHP within HTML and not HTML within PHP like so:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): $pid = $row ['pid']; ?>
<div class="single">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <br />
            <a href="MyOnlineStore/product.php?id=<?php echo $pid; ?>">View Details</a>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $path.$row['filename']; ?>" rel="lightbox[plants]" title="<?php echo $row['alttext']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $path.$row['filename']; ?>" alt="Plants: image 1 0f 4 thumb" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

to answer your question 'how to echo $pid?' answer is `echo $pid;`

You're also opening using php open-close tags `<?php ?>` inside php, which will not work.

Let me suggest you to have a read at http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php and get familiar with basic principles of php.

Futhermore, as @Juanid Bhura wrote

`Its considered a better practice to echo PHP within HTML and not HTML within PHP`

Comment: A space between the variable name and the array access operator `[]` is perfectly legal. So there is nothing wrong with `$pid = $row ['pid'];` and you can even write `$pid = $row [ 'pid' ];`.

Comment: so it seems to be! I wasn't aware of that, but still consider it being good practice to avoid using spaces in variable names

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong; you have php syntax -in- php syntax.  Change your code to the following, and it should work:

```
echo '<div class="single"><div class="wrap">

<div style="text-align:center;">
 <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/snarfer.php?id=' . $pid . '">Comments</a>

</br>
<a href="MyOnlineStore/product.php?id=' . $pid . '">View Details</a>
</div>
<a href="'.$path.$row['filename'].'" rel="lightbox[plants]" title="'.$row['alttext'].'"><img src="'.$path.$row['filename'].'" alt="Plants: image 1 0f 4 thumb" /></a>
</div>
</div>';
```

Comment: A space between the variable name and the array access operator `[]` is perfectly legal. So there is nothing wrong with `$pid = $row ['pid'];` and you can even write `$pid = $row [ 'pid' ];`.

Comment: @Arjan Welp..  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

`<a href="MyOnlineStore/product.php?id='.$pid.'">View Details</a>`

`<?php echo $pid?>` inside quotes is ignored as a normal string and not parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pid=$row ['pid'];
    echo '<div class="single"><div class="wrap">

 <div style="text-align:center;">
     <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/snarfer.php?id='. $pid .'">Comments</a>

 </br>
<a href="MyOnlineStore/product.php?id='.$pid.'">View Details</a>
 </div>
 <a href="'.$path.$row['filename'].'" rel="lightbox[plants]" title="'.$row['alttext'].'"><img src="'.$path.$row['filename'].'" alt="Plants: image 1 0f 4 thumb" /></a>
 </div>
</div>';
}
```